# Spring + mongodb получение вложенных полей

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

есть записи следующего формата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на код, который я написал: https://github.com/BurykinID/mongoSpring

Хочу получить записи по _id. Все практически получилось за исключением того, что на get запрос программа возвращает несколько искаженные данные. допустим у params.param.id null.
Пример ответа для данной записи: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y5sVvRBBCRaHp25FuhB_79KHR_hf2jeH
Он же только в скриншоте: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос делаю следующим образом: `http://localhost:8080/offers/id=9a4b7791-c0ff-11e5-84d2-0cc47a13d3da` 
Как можно исправить данные искажения?

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема. Вы на что "грешите" - на БД или на свой код?

Comment: Видимо я не понимаю что-то во взаимодействии с mongodb и спринга. В коде своем нашел ошибку, исправил теперь выдает корректное значение CatigoryID, ошибка с названием класса и переменной. А вот что со значениями params.param.id не понимаю

Comment: к сожалению, по Spring ничем Вам не могу помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге переименовал поле params.param.id на params.param.IsId оно получается без проблем. Видимо возникает конфликт между _id и id при запросе в mongo через Spring